# varchar vs datetime in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was having problem in retrieving from SQL Server so I posted this [question][1]

I did not get any suitable answers. So I have changed the column datatype from `datetime` to `varchar` and now it works fine.

```
SELECT *  
FROM test
WHERE (timeStamp BETWEEN '05-09-2013 18:23:57' AND '05-09-2013 18:23:59')
```

But my query if `varchar` datatype can play the role of `datetime` and in `varchar` we can also store the string then why sql provides `datetime` datatype? I know `varchar` occupies more space than `datetime`. I would like to know other reasons.

Comment: My strong suggestion, change it back to `datetime`.

Comment: @MartinSmith If i do so I can not retrive using this query" SELECT     *  FROM            test
WHERE        (timeStamp BETWEEN '05-09-2013 18:23:57' AND '05-09-2013 18:23:59')"

Comment: @javaBeginner - It is certainly possible to do a range query on `datetime` datatype. Changing it to an inappropriate datatype is not the way to resolve whatever issue you were having.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I had problem so i am changing to varchar.But i wanted to know the reason why shouldnt I keep it as varchar?

Comment: For the same reason you shouldn't use a watermelon to hit a nail into a wall. Just because it might work, doesn't make it right, and sooner or later, it's going to explode in your face.

Comment: @MartinSmith you can see the link that i posted in my original question(link given in this question).Its not retriving. If you want any other information then please tell me

Comment: Changing to `varchar` will increase your problems, because varchar and dattime have different semantics, and they must be stored in exact data type.

Comment: You cannot do date/time math on a `varchar` column.... and you'll constantly have to convert back and forth from and to `DATETIME` for that... and storing as a `Varchar` you're depending on the regional/locale settings to properly interpret the date ..... and and and .....

Comment: That string format you are using won't even be correct for range queries. It would need to be `yyyymmdd` to work correctly. And then you've still got the issues of inefficient storage, validating correct dates, constantly needing to cast to use datetime functions.

Comment: Also see: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change datatype of your column to `datetime`. You can do your query IF you'll use datetime instead of varchar in where clause:

```
select *
from test
where timeStamp between convert(datetime, '2013-09-05 18:23:57', 120) and convert(datetime, '2013-09-05 18:23:59', 120)
```

I'm pretty sure it would work even with implicit cast if you use ISO format of date:

```
select *
from test
where timeStamp between '2013-09-05 18:23:57' and '2013-09-05 18:23:59'
```

Here's more info about [cast and convert](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: you wrote 120 ,May i know why?

Comment: @javaBeginner yep, updated answer. 120 is 'ODBC canonical format' - yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)

Comment: The ISO format only works correctly on all regional settings for the newer datatypes such as `date`/`datetime2`. For the older datatypes you need the unseparated format without the dashes. e.g. this fails `SET LANGUAGE Italian; SELECT CAST( '2013-09-20 18:23:57'  AS DATETIME)`

Comment: @MartinSmith yep, actually at my work I'm always using yyyymmdd format because I've started to work with SQL 2000, but when I came to SO I've found that yyyy-mm-dd format is more often used by SQL gurus in answers, thanks for note anyway

Comment: @RomanPekar Please see the updated question after i run your code

Comment: @MartinSmith what ever i do,i get only null values

Comment: The unambiguous formats are Unambiguous formats 
YYYYMMDD  
YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS 
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS 

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10898/understanding-datetime-column-part-ii.aspx

Comment: @javaBeginner queries in your question and in your screenshot are different (you're using 'dd-mm-yyyy' format again on your screenshot)

Answer (score 2):

Another reason apart from space is this:

**Datetime** has other functions like picking up the day, year, month,hours,minutes,seconds etc so that you don't have to write it for yourself. If you use **varchar** then it will be your responsibility to provide functions for future use. You should use split function to retrive the part of date you want.

Another is that a query on a **varchar** works slower when compared to **Datetime** when you use to conditions to compare month / day/ year

Answer (score 1):

Always use proper DATETIME datatype to store date and time values. Refer this for more information
http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10902/understanding-datetime-column-part-iv.aspx